# Hash GPS coordinates to be unrecoverable yet still representative?

Tags: database, encryption, hash, gps

So I would like to write a program that allow computers that know their GPS locations, to store their location into a database as well as put out the 'locations' of the other computers and see which other similar computers are within a certain approximate range.

How ever I would also like people to be able to access that database without knowing the exact location of other computers, just which ones are an approximate range, it can be a wide variety of ranges, say all computers within 3 and no computers more than 5 miles away but the ones in the middle can go either way. I'm thinking I can somehow hash it before putting it into the database.  Any thoughts as to how I can do that?

Thank you!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash

Comment: I like Geohash.. will probably use, same that was a comment not an answer, would've picked you for best answer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An coordinate pair (latitude, longitude) can be represented by two integers (each 4 byte) by multiplying with 10 000 000. (1E7) 
Now your task is reduced to encrypt two integers.

Comment: How does encryption help with proximity queries?

Comment: it does not help, for proxmity queries  there are geo spatial indexes, like quad tree.